# PHP file is not recompiled

Tags: php

I'm using bitnami/php-fpm:7.4 and httpd:2.4 in docker container. I have a php script:

```php
<?php
echo time();
```

it return timestamp, but when I add 'test'

```php
<?php
echo time() . 'test';
```

and refresh the page, it still returns time, but with different numbers. Seams like the php file is not recompiled on page refresh. It adds 'test' after a while (a minute or so). Can I remove that caching?

Comment: PHP isn't compiled and doesn't cache. Something between PHP and your eyeballs might cache, but we have no way to know about any of that.

Comment: This is most likely the browser caching the response, not PHP.

Comment: @Sammitch PHP is cached if you have opcache enabled. So it may take a few minutes for the server to take up the changes.

Comment: @CodeSpirit possibly true, but unless you've intentionally modified the default settings OpCache checks the file timestamp on every request. Someone who had modified these settings wouldn't be asking this question.